# Transpile with Babel without transpiling JSX

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, reactjs

Is it possible to transpile using `babel.transform` without touching the JSX? I would like to leave the JSX in place to use an alternative JSX interpreter which is to be performed after the Babel transpilation takes place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when transpiling JSX, you'd have a configuration like

```
{
  presets: ['es2015', 'react']
}
```

In your case however, you're essentially looking to leave out 'react` without causing Babel to throw a syntax error for JSX. This can be accomplished by only enabling the plugin for the parsing JSX syntax without enabling the plugin for converting JSX into JS: http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-jsx/

```
{
  presets: ['es2015'],
  plugins: ['syntax-jsx']
}
```

and ensuring you install the plugin with `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-synax-jsx`.